# AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Program type already present: com.google.common.annotations.GwtCompatible","sources":[{}],"tool":"D8"}

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, android-build

There are similar post for this type of error but i can't figure what is wrong in my case.

The error is:

> AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Program type already present: com.google.common.annotations.GwtCompatible","sources":[{}],"tool":"D8"}
>
> ```
> :app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForFlavorDevDebug  FAILED
> ```

This is part of the output when running ./gradlew app:dependencies:

```
flavorDevDebugAndroidTestCompileClasspath - Resolved configuration for compilation for variant: flavorDevDebugAndroidTest
+--- :cloudtestingscreenshotter_lib:
+--- org.mockito:mockito-android:2.10.0
|    +--- org.mockito:mockito-core:2.10.0
|    |    +--- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:1.7.4
|    |    +--- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy-agent:1.7.4
|    |    \--- org.objenesis:objenesis:2.6
|    \--- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy-android:1.7.4
|         +--- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:1.7.4
|         \--- com.jakewharton.android.repackaged:dalvik-dx:1
|              \--- com.jakewharton.android.repackaged:libcore-dex:2
+--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1
+--- com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2
|    +--- com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1
|    |    +--- com.android.support.test:monitor:1.0.2
|    |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1
|    |    +--- junit:junit:4.12
|    |    |    \--- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.3
|    |    \--- net.sf.kxml:kxml2:2.3.0
|    +--- com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-idling-resource:3.0.2
|    +--- com.squareup:javawriter:2.1.1
|    +--- javax.inject:javax.inject:1
|    +--- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:1.3
|    |    \--- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.3
|    +--- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-integration:1.3
|    |    \--- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:1.3 (*)
|    \--- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:2.0.1
+--- com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-intents:3.0.2
|    +--- com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2 (*)
|    \--- com.android.support.test:rules:1.0.2
|         \--- com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2 (*)
+--- com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:3.0.2
|    +--- com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2 (*)
|    +--- com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-idling-resource:3.0.2
|    +--- com.android.support:design:27.1.1
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1
|    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.1
|    |    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1
|    |    |    |    \--- android.arch.lifecycle:runtime:1.1.0
|    |    |    |         +--- android.arch.lifecycle:common:1.1.0
|    |    |    |         |    \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:26.1.0 -> 27.1.1
|    |    |    |         +--- android.arch.core:common:1.1.0
|    |    |    |         |    \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:26.1.0 -> 27.1.1
|    |    |    |         \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:26.1.0 -> 27.1.1
|    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-media-compat:27.1.1
|    |    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1
|    |    |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.1 (*)
|    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-core-utils:27.1.1
|    |    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1
|    |    |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.1 (*)
|    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-core-ui:27.1.1
|    |    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1
|    |    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.1 (*)
|    |    |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-core-utils:27.1.1 (*)
|    |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-fragment:27.1.1
|    |    |         +--- com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.1 (*)
|    |    |         +--- com.android.support:support-core-ui:27.1.1 (*)
|    |    |         +--- com.android.support:support-core-utils:27.1.1 (*)
|    |    |         +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1
|    |    |         +--- android.arch.lifecycle:livedata-core:1.1.0
|    |    |         |    +--- android.arch.lifecycle:common:1.1.0 (*)
|    |    |         |    +--- android.arch.core:common:1.1.0 (*)
|    |    |         |    \--- android.arch.core:runtime:1.1.0
|    |    |         |         \--- android.arch.core:common:1.1.0 (*)
|    |    |         \--- android.arch.lifecycle:viewmodel:1.1.0
|    |    +--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1
|    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1
|    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-core-utils:27.1.1 (*)
|    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-fragment:27.1.1 (*)
|    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:27.1.1
|    |    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1
|    |    |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.1 (*)
|    |    |    \--- com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:27.1.1
|    |    |         +--- com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:27.1.1 (*)
|    |    |         \--- com.android.support:support-core-ui:27.1.1 (*)
|    |    +--- com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1
|    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1
|    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.1 (*)
|    |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-core-ui:27.1.1 (*)
|    |    \--- com.android.support:transition:27.1.1
|    |         +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1
|    |         \--- com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.1 (*)
|    +--- com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1 (*)
|    +--- com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.1 (*)
|    +--- com.android.support:support-core-utils:27.1.1 (*)
|    \--- com.google.android.apps.common.testing.accessibility.framework:accessibility-test-framework:2.0
|         \--- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.3
+--- com.sun.mail:android-mail:1.6.0
|    \--- com.sun.mail:android-activation:1.6.0
+--- com.sun.mail:android-activation:1.6.0
+--- com.android.support:multidex-instrumentation:1.0.2
|    \--- com.android.support:multidex:1.0.2 -> 1.0.3
+--- com.google.apis:google-api-services-youtube:v3-rev180-1.22.0
|    \--- com.google.api-client:google-api-client:1.22.0
|         +--- com.google.oauth-client:google-oauth-client:1.22.0
|         |    +--- com.google.http-client:google-http-client:1.22.0
|         |    |    \--- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:1.3.9 -> 2.0.1
|         |    \--- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:1.3.9 -> 2.0.1
|         +--- com.google.http-client:google-http-client-jackson2:1.22.0
|         |    +--- com.google.http-client:google-http-client:1.22.0 (*)
|         |    \--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.1.3 -> 2.9.0
|         \--- com.google.guava:guava-jdk5:17.0
+--- com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3
+--- com.android.support:support-core-utils:27.1.1 (*)
+--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1 (*)
+--- com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:27.1.1
|    +--- com.android.support:support-media-compat:27.1.1 (*)
|    +--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1 (*)
|    \--- com.android.support:palette-v7:27.1.1
|         +--- com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.1 (*)
|         \--- com.android.support:support-core-utils:27.1.1 (*)
+--- com.android.support:design:27.1.1 (*)
+--- com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1 (*)
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.1
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth-api-phone:[15.0.1,16.0.0) -> 15.0.1
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:[15.0.1,16.0.0) -> 15.0.1
|    |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:[15.0.1] -> 15.0.1
|    |    |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0 -> 27.1.1 (*)
|    |    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:[15.0.1] -> 15.0.1
|    |    |         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:[15.0.1] -> 15.0.1 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:[15.0.1,16.0.0) -> 15.0.1 (*)
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:[15.0.1,16.0.0) -> 15.0.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth-base:[15.0.1] -> 15.0.1
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:[15.0.1,16.0.0) -> 15.0.1 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:[15.0.1,16.0.0) -> 15.0.1 (*)
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:[15.0.1,16.0.0) -> 15.0.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:[15.0.1,16.0.0) -> 15.0.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:[15.0.1,16.0.0) -> 15.0.1 (*)
|    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:[15.0.1,16.0.0) -> 15.0.1 (*)
+--- com.google.firebase:firebase-core:15.0.2
|    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:[15.0.2,16.0.0) -> 15.0.2
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:[15.0.1,16.0.0) -> 15.0.1 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:[15.0.2] -> 15.0.2
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-stats:[15.0.1,16.0.0) -> 15.0.1
|    |    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:[15.0.1] -> 15.0.1 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:[15.0.2] -> 15.0.2
|    |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-identifier:[15.0.1,16.0.0) -> 15.0.1
|    |    |    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:[15.0.1,16.0.0) -> 15.0.1 (*)
|    |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:[15.0.1,16.0.0) -> 15.0.1 (*)
|    |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:[15.0.2] -> 15.0.2
|    |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-stats:[15.0.1,16.0.0) -> 15.0.1 (*)
|    |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:[15.0.1,16.0.0) -> 15.0.1 (*)
|    |    |    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:[15.0.1,16.0.0) -> 15.0.1
|    |    |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:[15.0.1,16.0.0) -> 15.0.1 (*)
|    |    |    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:[15.0.1,16.0.0) -> 15.0.1 (*)
|    |    |    \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:[15.1.0,16.0.0) -> 15.1.0
|    |    |         +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:[15.0.1,16.0.0) -> 15.0.1 (*)
|    |    |         +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-stats:[15.0.1,16.0.0) -> 15.0.1 (*)
|    |    |         +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:[15.0.1,16.0.0) -> 15.0.1 (*)
|    |    |         +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:[15.0.1,16.0.0) -> 15.0.1 (*)
|    |    |         \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-iid-interop:[15.0.0,16.0.0) -> 15.0.0
|    |    |              +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:[15.0.1,16.0.0) -> 15.0.1 (*)
|    |    |              \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:[15.0.1,16.0.0) -> 15.0.1 (*)
|    |    \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:[15.0.1,16.0.0) -> 15.0.1 (*)
|    \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-measurement-connector-impl:[15.0.0,16.0.0) -> 15.0.0
|         +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:[15.0.1,16.0.0) -> 15.0.1 (*)
|         +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:[15.0.2] -> 15.0.2
|         +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:[15.0.2] -> 15.0.2 (*)
|         +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:[15.0.2] -> 15.0.2 (*)
|         +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:[15.0.1,16.0.0) -> 15.0.1 (*)
|         \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-measurement-connector:[15.0.0,16.0.0) -> 15.0.0
|              \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:[15.0.1,16.0.0) -> 15.0.1 (*)
+--- com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:15.0.2
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:[15.0.1,16.0.0) -> 15.0.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:[15.0.1,16.0.0) -> 15.0.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:[15.0.1,16.0.0) -> 15.0.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-core:[15.0.2,16.0.0) -> 15.0.2 (*)
|    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:[15.1.0] -> 15.1.0 (*)
|    \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-measurement-connector:[15.0.0,16.0.0) -> 15.0.0 (*)
+--- com.google.firebase:firebase-database:15.0.1
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:[15.0.1,16.0.0) -> 15.0.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:[15.0.1,16.0.0) -> 15.0.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:[15.0.1,16.0.0) -> 15.0.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-database-collection:[15.0.1,16.0.0) -> 15.0.1
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:[15.0.1,16.0.0) -> 15.0.1 (*)
|    \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-database-connection:[15.0.1] -> 15.0.1
|         +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:[15.0.1,16.0.0) -> 15.0.1 (*)
|         +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:[15.0.1,16.0.0) -> 15.0.2 (*)
|         \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:[15.0.1,16.0.0) -> 15.0.1 (*)
+--- com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:15.0.1
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:[15.0.1,16.0.0) -> 15.0.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:[15.0.1,16.0.0) -> 15.0.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:[15.0.1,16.0.0) -> 15.0.1 (*)
|    \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:[15.0.1,16.0.0) -> 15.0.1 (*)
+--- com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:15.0.2
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:[15.0.1,16.0.0) -> 15.0.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-flags:[15.0.1,16.0.0) -> 15.0.1
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:[15.0.1] -> 15.0.1 (*)
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:[15.0.1] -> 15.0.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:[15.0.2] -> 15.0.2
|    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:[15.0.2] -> 15.0.2 (*)
|    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:[15.0.1,16.0.0) -> 15.0.1 (*)
|    \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:[15.1.0,16.0.0) -> 15.1.0 (*)
+--- com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:15.1.0
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:[15.0.1,16.0.0) -> 15.0.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:[15.0.1,16.0.0) -> 15.0.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-flags:[15.0.1,16.0.0) -> 15.0.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:[15.0.1,16.0.0) -> 15.0.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:[15.0.1,16.0.0) -> 15.0.2 (*)
|    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-auth-interop:[15.0.2,16.0.0) -> 15.0.2
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:[15.0.1,16.0.0) -> 15.0.1 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:[15.0.1,16.0.0) -> 15.0.1 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:[15.0.1,16.0.0) -> 15.0.1 (*)
|    |    \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:[15.0.1,16.0.0) -> 15.0.1 (*)
|    \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:[15.0.1,16.0.0) -> 15.0.1 (*)
+--- com.google.firebase:firebase-invites:15.0.1
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-appinvite:[15.0.1,16.0.0) -> 15.0.2
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:[15.0.1,16.0.0) -> 15.0.1 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:[15.0.1,16.0.0) -> 15.0.1 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:[15.0.2] -> 15.0.2
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:[15.0.1,16.0.0) -> 15.0.1 (*)
|    |    \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-dynamic-links:[15.0.2] -> 15.0.2
|    |         +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:[15.0.1,16.0.0) -> 15.0.1 (*)
|    |         +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:[15.0.1,16.0.0) -> 15.0.1 (*)
|    |         +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:[15.0.2] -> 15.0.2
|    |         +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:[15.0.1,16.0.0) -> 15.0.1 (*)
|    |         +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:[15.0.2] -> 15.0.2 (*)
|    |         \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:[15.0.1,16.0.0) -> 15.0.1 (*)
|    \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:[15.0.1,16.0.0) -> 15.0.2 (*)
+--- com.google.firebase:firebase-config:15.0.2
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:[15.0.1,16.0.0) -> 15.0.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:[15.0.1,16.0.0) -> 15.0.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-phenotype:[15.0.1,16.0.0) -> 15.0.1
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:[15.0.1,16.0.0) -> 15.0.1 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:[15.0.1,16.0.0) -> 15.0.1 (*)
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:[15.0.1,16.0.0) -> 15.0.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:[15.0.1,16.0.0) -> 15.0.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-abt:[15.0.1,16.0.0) -> 15.0.1
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:[15.0.1,16.0.0) -> 15.0.1 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:[15.0.1,16.0.0) -> 15.0.2 (*)
|    |    \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:[15.0.1,16.0.0) -> 15.0.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:[15.0.1,16.0.0) -> 15.0.2 (*)
|    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:[15.0.1,16.0.0) -> 15.0.1 (*)
|    \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:[15.0.1,16.0.0) -> 15.1.0 (*)
+--- com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:15.0.1
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:[15.0.1,16.0.0) -> 15.0.1
|    |    +--- com.android.support:customtabs:26.1.0 -> 27.1.1
|    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.1 (*)
|    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1
|    |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-core-ui:27.1.1 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-base:[15.0.1] -> 15.0.1
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-identifier:[15.0.1,16.0.0) -> 15.0.1 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite:[15.0.1] -> 15.0.1
|    |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-base:[15.0.1] -> 15.0.1
|    |    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:[15.0.1,16.0.0) -> 15.0.1 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:[15.0.1,16.0.0) -> 15.0.1 (*)
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-gass:[15.0.1] -> 15.0.1
|    |         +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-base:[15.0.1] -> 15.0.1
|    |         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:[15.0.1,16.0.0) -> 15.0.1 (*)
|    \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:[15.0.1,16.0.0) -> 15.0.2 (*)
+--- com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:16.0.0
|    +--- com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.7.2
|    |    \--- com.squareup.okio:okio:1.6.0
|    +--- io.grpc:grpc-okhttp:1.8.0
|    |    +--- io.grpc:grpc-core:[1.8.0] -> 1.8.0
|    |    |    +--- io.grpc:grpc-context:1.8.0
|    |    |    +--- com.google.guava:guava:19.0
|    |    |    +--- com.google.errorprone:error_prone_annotations:2.0.19
|    |    |    +--- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:3.0.0 -> 2.0.1
|    |    |    +--- com.google.instrumentation:instrumentation-api:0.4.3
|    |    |    |    +--- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:3.0.0 -> 2.0.1
|    |    |    |    \--- com.google.guava:guava:19.0
|    |    |    +--- io.opencensus:opencensus-api:0.8.0
|    |    |    |    +--- com.google.errorprone:error_prone_annotations:2.0.19
|    |    |    |    \--- com.google.guava:guava:19.0
|    |    |    \--- io.opencensus:opencensus-contrib-grpc-metrics:0.8.0
|    |    |         +--- com.google.errorprone:error_prone_annotations:2.0.19
|    |    |         \--- io.opencensus:opencensus-api:0.8.0 (*)
|    |    +--- com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.5.0 -> 2.7.2 (*)
|    |    \--- com.squareup.okio:okio:1.6.0
|    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-core:[15.0.1,16.0.0) -> 15.0.2 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:[15.0.1,16.0.0) -> 15.0.1 (*)
|    +--- io.grpc:grpc-stub:1.8.0
|    |    \--- io.grpc:grpc-core:1.8.0 (*)
|    +--- android.arch.lifecycle:runtime:1.0.0 -> 1.1.0 (*)
|    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:[15.0.1,16.0.0) -> 15.0.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:[15.0.0,16.0.0) -> 15.0.0
|    |    \--- com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:[15.0.1,16.0.0) -> 15.0.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-database-collection:[15.0.1,16.0.0) -> 15.0.1 (*)
|    \--- io.grpc:grpc-protobuf-lite:1.8.0
|         +--- io.grpc:grpc-core:1.8.0 (*)
|         +--- com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1
|         \--- com.google.guava:guava:19.0
+--- com.android.billingclient:billing:1.0
|    \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:25.0.0 -> 27.1.1
+--- com.android.support:support-media-compat:27.1.1 (*)
+--- com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1 (*)
+--- com.android.support:customtabs:27.1.1 (*)
+--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.9.0
+--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.9.0
+--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.9.0
|    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.9.0
|    \--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.9.0
+--- com.chauthai.swipereveallayout:swipe-reveal-layout:1.4.0
|    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:24.0.0 -> 27.1.1 (*)
+--- com.koushikdutta.ion:ion:2.2.1
|    +--- com.koushikdutta.async:androidasync:2.2.1
|    \--- com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3
+--- io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.0.4
|    \--- org.reactivestreams:reactive-streams:1.0.0
+--- com.github.rholder:guava-retrying:2.0.0
|    \--- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:2.0.2 -> 2.0.1
+--- org.bluecabin.textoo:textoo:1.0.1
|    +--- com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.1 -> 27.1.1 (*)
|    \--- org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.11.7
\--- org.greenrobot:greendao:3.2.2
     \--- org.greenrobot:greendao-api:3.2.2
```

I am updating some dependencies, had solve a few problems before reaching here, but now i am stuck in this for too long.

I can't see nothing that points where the GwtCompatible class comes from.

Comment: I had a similar problem this week, took me about two hours to find a solution, but I had to update all of my google dependencies (in my case the problem was related to the gms libraries), also my AS as well, maye that's your case

Comment: The error was reported with all librarys updated, including gms and Firebase.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Going through the old painful way to detect any kind of conflicts, I remove one dependency at a time and finally found out that the conflict involved google api client.

The solution I apply was the same for [com.google.common.annotations.Beta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49574524/2700303) duplicate, that is excluding guava from the api implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I add configurations After defaultConfig in android/app/build.gradle and it work well.

**code:**

```
    configurations{
        all*.exclude module:'okhttp'
        all*.exclude module:'okio'
        all*.exclude module:'gson'
    }
```